# Cordova 6.1.1: warnings with XCode 7.3 in plugins InAppBrowser 1.4.0 and Geolocation 2.2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova 6.1.1 App that makes use of plugins:

- InAppBrowser 1.4.0
- Geolocation 2.2.0

With Android I have not problems, but when I try to build the App with XCode 7.3 I get some warnings that will not allow me to deploy the App to the App Store:

1. CDVInAppBrowser.m

   - 'UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use UIBarButtonItemStylePlain when minimum deployment target is iOS7 or later.
   - Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
   - Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supported interface orientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
2. CDVLocation.m

   - 'kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use kCLAuthorizationStatisAuthorizedAlways
   - 'locationServicesEnabled' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 4.0

I searched a lot over the Internet, but I didn't find a solution.
Any help?

Comment: The warnings with the word `deprecated` are clear - you are using deprecated iOS API that is no longer supported or recommended. The `Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument` is more serious - you are  trying to pass a `nil` argument to a method that does not accept a `nil` argument. Your app will crash if this line is called and this must be fixed before shipping. In both cases you must update your plugins to recent versions that use non-deprecated iOS API. If you have access to the source you may be able to fix the problems yourself.

Comment: Thank you Robotic Cat for your answer.
It seams that I didn't clearify the point.
The problem is with standard last versions of Cordova plugins.
Just to make a test, I just created a blank new App, with this following commands:
`cordova create testPlugin com.example.testplugin testPlugin`
`cd testPlugin`
`cordova platform add ios`
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`
Then I open XCode and try to run the App, and here are the warnings! Without no line of code from me!

Comment: It sounds like you need to contact Cordova support. I see that their website (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html) has a link to upgrading your Cordova version (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/upgrade.html) so make sure you are on the very latest version. I cannot think of any solution apart from using a different framework that is updated more frequently or just use Xcode & Swift.

Comment: I'm using latest Cordova version.
I just created two issues in Cordova JIRA hoping to get a solution there: [CB-11190](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11190) [CB-11189](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11189)

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Updated InAppBrowser to latest as well.

Comment: Same problem with XCode 7.3.1.

Comment: The problem is still there, no fixes from Cordova developers by now, but I tried to submit the App to App Store (it was an update of a previously distributed App) and it was accepted. I don't know if a new App with these warnings will be accepted.